# Map all SQL servers on a network with details

Tags: sql-server, database

A colleague has been given a task of documenting SQL Servers for a client, that has about 200 servers (on physical and virtual hardware) with a total of about 1000 databases.

- What servers are on the network?
- What hardware are they running on?
- Version of OS/SQL Server?
- What users have access to the server?

We have been googling for software to do this, but without luck. Does software like this exist, or do we have to roll our own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your colelague should talk to the admin team - most likely they have or shoult ahve something like Tivoli or SCCM / SCOM (System Center, Microsoft) in use and actually DO AHVE this information already.

Otherwise I would suggest SCOM (System Center Operations Manager) and SCCM (System Center Configuration Manager) to start managing those servers.

Comment: Yes to SCOM (if you have it)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of utilities that can do this. One that I was recently introduced to is pretty good, it's [ManagePC](http://managepc.net/) and it can collect the bulk of this information for you.

As for determining which users have access to the server, your client needs to be more specific. Do they want to know which users can access file shares on the servers, which users can access SQL server, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Quest has a (currently free) tool called [Discovery Wizard for SQL Server](http://www.quest.com/discovery-wizard-for-sql-server/) that can get you most of the data that you want.

It will search IP ranges or AD groups using various methods, and get information about servers (including OS level, how much memory, number of processors), the databases installed (including SQL version and service pack level), logins, etc.